# Email message python Grabbing parts of a message

Tags: python, email, imap

Ok so I am using the imap lib to download a message. I do not want to download the entire message only look at the attachment. Like for example when the message is recieved and downloaded as a whole the following .txt attachment is shown:

```
------=_Part_1476882_26131288.1342315902872--
------=_Part_1476883_28164997.1342315902872--
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; 
name=textplain_2.txt
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename=textplain_2.txt
Bhh
------=_Part_1476883_28164997.1342315902872--
```

The Bhh in the above message was the content of the text file. Is there some way to JUST download the attachment? I saw a tutorial on http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Python-Email-Libraries-part-2-IMAP/3/ which was talking about this but I wasn't sure how to download or get just the contents of the attached text file...

They suggested to do something like....

```
r, data = server.fetch(‘6’, ‘(UID BODY[TEXT])’)
r, data = server.fetch(‘6’, ‘(UID ENVELOPE)’)
r, data = server.fetch(‘2:5’, ‘(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT FROM)])
```

I was thinking it would be something along the lines of:

```
server.fetch(‘6’, ‘(UID BODY[ATTACHMENT???<-------])’)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to parse the [BODYSTRUCTURE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-7.4.2) of the message to determine what the section part number of the attachment in question is.

```
server.fetch(‘6’, ‘(UID BODYSTRUCTURE)’)
```

Then you will need to actually fetch the attachment you are looking for, the query will look something like this:

```
server.fetch('6', '(BODY[2.1])')
```

Note that the section part id is '2.1' in this example.